# Protobuf with Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I apologize ahead of time -- I think I am not experienced enough in Unity, C#, or even Protobufs to know why this isn't working.

I'm trying to use this plugin: https://github.com/5argon/protobuf-unity
I downloaded the official Google.Protobuf.Tools and linked to the protoc.exe. When I put a protoc file into my Unity project and try to compile it, an error pops up saying:

> Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\RealProjects\Robot Script\Packages\Google.Protobuf.Tools.3.6.0\tools\windows_x64', CommandLine='"C:/Users/Brian/Desktop/RealProjects/Robot Script/Assets\Protobuf\test.proto" --csharp_out C:/Users/Brian/Desktop/RealProjects/Robot Script/Assets\Protobuf  --proto_path C:/Users/Brian/Desktop/RealProjects/Robot Script/Assets\Protobuf ', CurrentDirectory=''
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process)
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ()
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
>   ProtobufUnityCompiler.CompileProtobufSystemPath (System.String protoFileSystemPath, System.String[] includePaths) (at Assets/Plugins/ProtobufUnityCompiler.cs:209)
>   ProtobufUnityCompiler.CompileAllInProject () (at Assets/Plugins/ProtobufUnityCompiler.cs:172)
>   ProtobufUnityCompiler.PreferencesItem () (at Assets/Plugins/ProtobufUnityCompiler.cs:90)
>   UnityEditor.PreferencesWindow.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/PreferencesWindow/PreferencesWindow.cs:373)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
>   Rethrow as TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:232)
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MethodBase.cs:115)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName, System.Object obj) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:291)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.Invoke (System.String methodName) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:284)
>   UnityEditor.HostView.OldOnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/HostView.cs:103)
>   UnityEngine.Experimental.UIElements.IMGUIContainer.DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event evt) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/UIElements/IMGUIContainer.cs:206)

I'm stuck and I don't know how to debug this.

Comment: Did you do step 2 of the installation instructions?  `You can access the settings in Preferences > Protobuf. Here you need to put a path to your protoc executable.`

Comment: Yes, I linked it to Google.Protobuf.Tools.3.6.0/tools/windows_x64/

Comment: That's the directory.  You need to put the *executable* name in there too.  Notice the error.  It's saying `C:\Users\Brian\Desktop\RealProjects\Robot Script\Packages\Google.Protobuf.Tools.3.6.0\tools\windows_x64` is the application name

Comment: I tried that, but it seems as if the plugin is faulty -- I just ended up using the Protobuf manually. Thank you for trying to help!